# Move from one layout to another using button

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, onclicklistener

I want to move from one xml to another. The other xml is in resetView method. How should I do it . Please help. I can also add a button on the first layout . On clicking that button I want move to the other xml layout i.e astigmatism test layout. How should I do it?? The code is as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.astigmatism_image);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(test_image);

    }



    private void resetView(){
        setContentView(R.layout.astigmatismtest);
        setObjects();
        int a[] = { R.id.leftEye, R.id.rightEye };
        setOnClickListener(a);


    }
```

Comment: Amy, you mean when you click button, you want to show another layout???

Comment: @Aniruddha:Thanx a lot . I could fix it.

Comment: Also I have written a similar code aspublic void resetView1(){setContentView(R.layout.ishiharacolortest);setObjects();((Button) findViewById R.id.startcolortest)).setOnClickListener(this);}@Overridepublic void onClick(View v) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub switch (v.getId()) {case R.id.startcolortest:resetView1();
break;case R.id.backtoMain:backToMain R.string.ishiharacolor);break;case R.id.backtoTest:resetView1();break;case R.id.backtoTests:backToMain R.string.tests);break;default:calculateResult((String) v.getTag());
changeObject();}}

Comment: But here I after moving to the next xml the test does not start, What could be the error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `resetView()` when you click the button. Like,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{                       
    @Override           
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {               
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub               
       resetView()          
     }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the setContentView method in the onClick method of your ClickListener

```
Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSwitchLayout);
testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    setContentView(R.layout.astigmatismtest);
    }
});
```